# Splitting data access and catching data to form

Tags: c#, class, oop

In my project I'm trying to write code that will be nice to understand. 
I currently split my data access functions in a seperate class.

What I'm trying to achieve however, is to catch the errors back to my form. I am not getting this currently and I was wondering why.

In my form I have the following code:

```
private void btn_Save_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (dal.updatePerson(ObjectAfterSaving))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Updated!");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("error");
    };
}
```

In my dal object (derived from the `DataAccess_Person class`), I have the following method:

```
public bool updatePerson(Person p)
{

    conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE Person
    SET PersonName = @PersonName
    WHERE PersonID = @PersonID", conn);
    command.Parameters.Add("@PersonName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = p.Name
    {
        try
        {
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                conn.Open();
            }

            int a = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            if (a > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: let's say if my method falls in the catch. Will my front end (form) show it (Sql Exception for example) ? Or will i just get 'error' ? And If I will just get error, how I can improve my code to show the Exception instead of error?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to catch the exception in `btn_Save_ItemClick` only? Do you want to catch it inside `updatePerson` then throw it again so you can access it from the caller method? Or do you just want to return the error message to the caller method? Also, note that you're not currently assigning `ex.ToString()` to any variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way is to remove the try catch from your DAL and add it to the form.  For example:

```
private void btn_Save_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{       
    var result = "Success";

    try
    {
        dal.updatePerson(ObjectAfterSaving);            
    }
    catch (SqlException sqlEx)
    {
        result = sqlEx.Message;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result = ex.Message;
    }

    MessageBox.Show(result);
}
```

Just note that there's a lot of ways you can do this.  My preference is to not include DAL specific exception types in my UI.  Instead I may return a custom result type that has an errorcode and message and let my UI display that or generate a custom message based on the error code.

Answer (score 1):

You‘ll just get „error“ in case of a `SqlException`. All other exceptions will crash your program if you don‘t have a global exception handler. If you want to show the error message you could introduce an `out` variable for the error message:

```
bool successful = MyMethod(out string errorMessage)
if (!successful)
{
    MessageBox.Show(errorMessage);
}

public bool MyMethod(out string errorMessage)
{
    errorMessage = "";
    try
    {
        // do some stuff
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        errorMessage = ex.Message;
        return false;
    }
}
```